# problem in printing content in files and folder comparison

Tags: python, file-comparison

I am trying to print difference between 2 folders and files. It shows me the content are different but I want it to actually print the differences which are not present in other folder with same file name.

I have a script in which I used mmap to read the contents. So far it can show me which files are different but not actually printing the exact differences

```
import os
import mmap

def compare_files(file1: str, file2: str) -> bool:
    """Function to compare files."""

with open(file1, 'rb') as f1, open(file2, 'rb') as f2:
    size1 = f1.seek(0, 2)
    size2 = f2.seek(0, 2)
    if size1 != size2:
        return False
    if size1 == 0:
        return True

    with mmap.mmap(f1.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as mm1, \
    mmap.mmap(f2.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as mm2:
        return mm1[0:] == mm2[0:]

def compare_folders(folder1: str, folder2: str) -> None:
    differences_found = False

# Compare files in folder1
for root1, dirs, files in os.walk(folder1):
    for file in files:
        file1 = os.path.join(root1, file)
        root2 = root1.replace(folder1, folder2, 1)
        file2 = os.path.join(root2, file)
        if not os.path.isfile(file2):
            print(f"File {file} exists in {root1} but not in {root2}")
            differences_found = True
        else:
            # If the file exists in both folders, compare them
            if not compare_files(file1, file2):
                print(f"Files {file} differ in {root1} and {root2}")
                differences_found = True

# Compare files in folder2
for root2, dirs, files in os.walk(folder2):
    for file in files:
        root1 = root2.replace(folder2, folder1, 1)
        file1 = os.path.join(root1, file)
        file2 = os.path.join(root2, file)
        if not os.path.isfile(file1):
            print(f"File {file} exists in {root2} but not in {root1}")
            differences_found = True

if not differences_found:
    print("No differences found between the files in the two folders.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder1 = input("Enter path to the first folder: ")
    folder2 = input("Enter path to the second folder: ")

    compare_folders(folder1, folder2)
```

Comment: You have a script you say?  What language are we talking about.  Can we see it ?  Show the results in text form, but if you need a picture you can embed it to the question.  As of now, the question is more about theory than getting a solution.

Comment: If I was using asp classic to do this, I would read the two files, put the values from the files into seperate arrays so i can step through them to compare.  Then when it detected x <> y , write those values to either another array or create a new file with those values, and then just print that.  It would be most efficient to gather all the different values first, put them into something you can use to show the changes such as a new file or array or what ever, then just print that.

Comment: I am using python. I posted the script. Please take a look

Comment: TY, i updated the tag request so python experts can find this.

Comment: What do you mean by printing differences ? Filenames or filenames with content if present in both the locaitons ?

Comment: It's quite expensive to compare each file byte-by-byte.  Typically, if the size and the last modification time are the same, then they are the same file.  `os.stat` can get you that information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)

```
import difflib

def write_difference(file1: str, file2: str) -> str:
    d = difflib.Differ()
    diff = d.compare(file1, file2)
    return '\n'.join(diff)
```